# how to combine a single column of 2 tables while selecting the other columns separately

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have 2 queries like :

```
select id, count(something) selected from table1...;
select id, count(something) rejected from table2...;
```

The first query gives me

```
id selected
------------
2  4
3  5
```

The second query gives me

```
id rejected
------------
1  12
3  13
```

I wish to combine them into the following form through a single query

```
id selected rejected
--------------------
1  null      12
2  4         null 
3  5         13
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to simulate `SQL Server`'s `FULL OUTER JOIN` by combining the `UNION`ed results of `LEFT and RIGHT` joins (*but in my case both are `LEFT JOIN` as I used to to this*)

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.selected, b.rejected
FROM    (selectedQuery) a
        LEFT JOIN (rejectedQuery) b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
UNION 
SELECT  a.ID, b.selected, a.rejected 
FROM    (rejectedQuery) a
        LEFT JOIN (selectedQuery) b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a1780/7)

**UPDATE 1**

PostgreSQL Supports `FULL OUTER JOIN` (*my bad*)

```
SELECT  COALESCE(a.ID,b.id) ID, a.selected, b.rejected
FROM    selectedQuery a
        FULL OUTER JOIN rejectedQuery b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a1780/13)

Comment: Is SQL Server's `FULL OUTER JOIN` different to PostgreSQL's `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @CraigRinger my bad, i thought `postgresql` doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`. thanks. I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 2):

Given some expressions that return your data:

```
select
 column1 id,
 column2 selected
from (values (2 , 4),(3, 5)) table1;

 id | selected 
----+----------
  2 |        4
  3 |        5
(2 rows)
```

```
select
 column1 id,
 column2 rejected 
from (values (1 , 12),(3, 13)) table2
dbornside-# ;
 id | rejected 
----+----------
  1 |       12
  3 |       13
(2 rows)
```

The usual inner join does not produce the correct results; only rows in *both* relations are shown

```
select * from 
     (select column1 id, column2 selected from (values (2 , 4),(3, 5)) table1) table1
join (select column1 id, column2 rejected from (values (1 , 12),(3, 13)) table2) table2 
on table1.id = table2.id;

 id | selected | id | rejected 
----+----------+----+----------
  3 |        5 |  3 |       13
(1 row)
```

To get *all* of the rows from the right table, you need a `right outer join`, rows from the left is a `left outer join`;  to get both you use a [`full outer join`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN):

```
select * 
from (select column1 id, column2 selected from (values (2 , 4),(3, 5)) table1) table1
FULL OUTER JOIN ( select column1 id, column2 rejected from (values (1 , 12),(3, 13)) table2) table2 
on table1.id = table2.id;

 id | selected | id | rejected 
----+----------+----+----------
  2 |        4 |    |         
  3 |        5 |  3 |       13
    |          |  1 |       12
(3 rows)
```

This looks a little odd, though.  that's because `table1.id` is not the same column as `table2.id`; and certain values are just not present in both tables.  We can gather them together in the same step with a `coalesce()`:

```
select COALESCE(table1.id, table2.id) id,
       selected,
       rejected
from (select column1 id, column2 selected from (values (2 , 4),(3, 5)) table1) table1 
full outer join ( select column1 id, column2 rejected from (values (1 , 12),(3, 13)) table2) table2 
on table1.id = table2.id;

 id | selected | rejected 
----+----------+----------
  2 |        4 |         
  3 |        5 |       13
  1 |          |       12
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you use a JOIN in the id column? e.g.

```
SELECT s.id, COUNT(s.something) selected, COUNT(r.something) rejected
FROM table1 s
INNER JOIN table2 r ON r.id = s.id
```